# Are nested aggregate functions allowed/not allowed by SQL standard?

Tags: sql, documentation, standards, iso

My question is strictly related to the ISO SQL standard, and not some of its implementations like Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL etc.

The question is:
Are nested aggregate functions allowed/forbidden by the SQL standard? For example, the following query:

```
select MAX(COUNT(*))
from a_table
group by a_column
```

In particular, I'm reading the documentation available [at this link](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Developer_FAQ#Where_can_I_get_a_copy_of_the_SQL_standards.3F), but I can't find any reference about this

As far as I know, Oracle allows this, but MySQL and PostgreSQL not, so I was wondering if somebody that knows the standard better than me, can tell if it's a grey area where different implementations can do what they want, or if there are some constraints on the standard

Comment: I can't find anything in ISO 9075 saying it should be allowed. (Would supposedly be an optional feature.)

Comment: What would be the point of the example SQL statement you’ve provided? As both aggregates are governed by the GROUP BY, MAX is operating on a single value (the COUNT) so has no effect on the result. Do you have an example of a nested aggregate where, if the query is valid, the nesting has an impact?

Comment: @NickW the “max count”, so u count for each group, and you get just the highest count

Comment: @jarlh so you would say that it’s in the grey are where each implementations can do whatever they want

Comment: But each group only has one count, so the max count per group and the count per group will always be the same and therefore the max is redundant

Comment: I'd say as it's not covered by the standard (afaik), it's an extension. (All vendors have their own extensions.)